# Create multiple functions in one Azure Function App

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I want to create multiple python Azure Functions within one Azure Functions App using the azure cli/core tools. One http triggered function and one blob triggered function.

I have the following folder structure:

```
├── azure-functions
│   ├── az-func-blob
│   │   ├── .python_packages
│   │   ├── .vscode
│   │   ├── .gitignore
│   │   ├── function_app.py
│   │   ├── host.json
│   │   ├── local_settings.json
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── az-func-http
│   │   ├── .python_packages
│   │   ├── .vscode
│   │   ├── .gitignore
│   │   ├── function_app.py
│   │   ├── host.json
│   │   ├── local_settings.json
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── README.md
```

Note: I created the individual function directories with the following commands within my project dir "azure-functions":

1. Blob function:

   `func init az-func-blob --worker-runtime python --model V2`

   `cd az-func-blob`

   `func new --template "Blob trigger" --name BlobTrigger`
2. Http function:

   `func init az-func-http --worker-runtime python --model V2`

   `cd az-func-http`

   `func new --template "HTTP trigger" --name HTTPTrigger`

If I navigate to the directory of one of these functions and run the command `func azure functionapp publish SPIEFUNC2` it works fine. However running this command again in the other function directory will overwrite the Trigger/Function in Azure instead of appending a new one even though the trigger names are different.
Apparently that's just how it works in Azure but I don't know how to create multiple functions within one Function app.

I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079549/deploying-multiple-function-under-same-azure-function-app-not-working) where someone suggested to use the same "host.json" for all functions. I don't know how to do this as every host.json is exactly the same anyway and looks like this:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain in detail how to get set this up using only one Azure Function App instead of multiple function apps?

Comment: just run `func init` once and `func new` twice. here you are creating a function app each time (`func init`) but you only need to do that once really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain in detail how to get set this up using only one Azure Function App instead of multiple function apps?

I am able to deploy multiple functions to a Function App using `func azure functionapp publish <function_APP_Name>` command.

Thanks **@Thomas** for the comment, you need to run `func init --worker-runtime python --model V2`  command once and `func new` twice.

- I have created one Http Triggered Function and Blob Triggered Function as shown below-

[image]

- When you will run `func init --worker-runtime python --model V2`, all the default files will get created for a function. Upon running `func new`, it will add the triggers in it.

I have deployed the functions to the function app and got successful deployed output.

[image]
[image]

I am able to see the functions in the function app.

[image]

***Output***-

[image]