# Azure Function Python V2 multiple function in one Function App

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm looking for guidance on creating a project structure for multiple functions in one Azure Function App. This is the post I read before [Create multiple functions in one Azure Function App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678603/create-multiple-functions-in-one-azure-function-app)

There are two things I can't seem to find a good answer:

1. Use Visual Studio Code to deploy multiple functions.
2. From the link above, it seems that I have to create a new function first, but the `func azure functionapp publish <App Name>` is used to publish app to an existing function.

I tried to deploy using VSCode, and it ended up overwriting to another function.

Comment: `func azure functionapp publish <App Name>` command will publish the local function to an existing function app.

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin, it must be done via command line, right? Does VSCode support?

Comment: You can deploy both ways

Comment: Update - it overwrote another function after I ran the `func azure functionapp...`

Comment: Did you mean if you are deploying to an existing function app having one function in it, it is getting overwritten?

Comment: Yes. I have two different folders. I navigated to each folder to run the `func azure functionapp..` . One overwrote another. I checked in Azure Portal and only saw 1 (the latter one)

Comment: You need to add all your function code to a single function_app.py file

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin if that is the case then why would we need to different folder? Are you suggesting me to copy all code to `function_app.py` . And this file needs to be in both folders?

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure? You need to have a folder structure like [this](https://i.imgur.com/IWqxgiZ.png) and add all type of triggers in `function_app.py` file

Comment: I've followed exactly like the one in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678603/create-multiple-functions-in-one-azure-function-app . Are you saying that each `function_app.py` need to have all triggers? (

Comment: Please share your folder structure to help you better

Comment: Your folder should have only one `function_app.py` file. You need to run `func init --worker-runtime python --model V2` command once to create all the default files needed for a function and run `func new` for adding triggers in it

Comment: I think you missed the point. Your structure has 1 folder only and it doesn't indicate two different functions. The structure in this post has two folders https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678603/create-multiple-functions-in-one-azure-function-app 

I made it work by copying all triggers and putting them on all function_app.py.

Comment: Yes, in that post project structure created incorrectly, you don't need to run `func init` twice as it create different folders. In local, folders acts as a Function app, so if you will execute `func init` twice it will create two function app then `func new` will create separate triggers. In order to resolve the issue and deploy the multiple functions once, you need to create one function and add all your trigger to a single `funnction_app.py` file

Comment: I'm very confused here. In your structure, I see only 1 function_app.py. Let's say I need 3 different functions (2 timer triggers, 1 http). They are all very complex. Are you saying code of all 3 functions are in a single function_app.py?

Comment: Yes, after executing `func init` once if you will run `func new` thrice to create 2 timer trigger function and one HTTP trigger function, you will see all the codes will get added in the same `function_app.py` file.

Comment: It sounds like a product limitation doesn't it? Imagine all complex code of 3 functions in one `function_app.py`. It will be a mess because they do differently. Thank you for your info.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy multiple functions at once you need to execute **`func init --worker-runtime python --model V2`** command once which will create all the default files needed for a function. Then you can run **`func new`** command many times if you would like to add different trigger functions in it.

If you will run `func new` thrice for creating one HTTP triggered function and 2 timer trigger function then the folder structure and `function_app.py` would look like below-

**Folder Structure**-

[image]

**function_app.py**-

```py
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 */5 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def TimerTriggerFunction(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

@app.route(route="HttpTriggeredFunction", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def HttpTriggeredFunction(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 0 0/1 * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def TimerTriggeredFunction2(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

You can either deploy using `func azure functionapp publish <function_APP_Name>` command or vs code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Portal**-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm not sure if it can be better with different Python files instead of one. Practically, no one would put all the code of 3 functions in a single file like that. I'd expect the `function_app.py` contains all the triggers, but the logic of each function is stored separately.

Comment: @indp Yes, you can try to store the logic of each function separately

Comment: How is it possible that you said all code must be in the same function_app.py? Do you have an example?

Comment: I am not sure if it is feasible, that's why I suggested you to try